# IllegalMonitorStateException in Thread wait notify

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on one task where i am having n threads and each thread will print nth number sequentially[1 to n]  .where each thread is waiting and notifying each other .
for Ex:-
if we are having 6 Threads then 1st thread should print 1,2nd thread should print 2 and so on.[in sequence 1 to 6]
when i am running below program i am getting IllegalMonitorStateException .

```
package interviews;
public class NumerPrintingwithThreadCount {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int Max =6;
    Integer [] o = new Integer [Max];
    for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++) {
        o[i] = new Integer(i);
    }
    PrintingThread []tt = new PrintingThread [Max];

    for (int i = 0; i <Max; i++) {
        Integer obj1 =o[i];
        Integer obj2=null;
        if(i==Max-1){
        obj2 = o[0];
        }
        else{
        obj2=o[i+1];
        }
        PrintingThread t=new PrintingThread(obj1, obj2,0);
        tt[i]=t;
    }
    for (int i=tt.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
        tt[i].setName("Thread"+1);
        tt[i].start();
        Thread.sleep(1);
    }  
}
}  
class PrintingThread extends Thread{
    Integer object1=null;
    Integer object2=null;
    int min =0;
    public PrintingThread(Integer obj1 ,Integer obj2, int min) {
        this.object1=obj1;
        this.object2=obj2;
        this.min=min;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(min==object1.intValue())
            {
                object2.notify();
            }else{
                synchronized (object2) {
                    object2.wait();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            object2.notify();
    }
}
```

Comment: a formatter would help to read the code... also the actual exception stacktrace

Comment: Please, clean up your code (remove comments, methods unrelated to your problem) and post exception details (stack trace, problematic line of code).

Comment: `notify` outside a synchronized block produces an `IllegalMonitorStateException`...

Comment: and @Reimeus means this - `object2.notify();`. Also, it is better to *handle InterruptedException* instead of *throwing* it..

Comment: Exception in thread "Thread1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
 at interviews.PrintingThread.run(NumerPrintingwithThreadCount.java:105)

and here i am printing threadNames which i can put 1,2,3,..for solving problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [Object.notify()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify())

> This method should only be called by a thread that is the owner of
>   this object's monitor. A thread becomes the owner of the object's
>   monitor in one of three ways:
>
> - By executing a synchronized instance method of that object.
> - By executing the body of a synchronized statement that synchronizes on the object.
> - For objects of type Class, by executing a synchronized static method of that class.

You must synchronize the object you are calling notify on.

Note: as wait() can either miss a notify or wake spuriously, you should associate a state change with a notify/wait. i.e. check the state change on wait() and introduce a state change on notify()

Comment: sir after adding synchronized block its printing only thread1. its not notifying other objects.
as by 1st thread i am notifying 2 but 2ndthread printing is not coming. :-(

Comment: @Arun when you notify and the thread is not already waiting it will be lost. If the thread then wait unconditionally it waits forever. You need to add a state change to check on.

Comment: @Arun the other thing is that the Thread name is currently always "Thread1"

Comment: @andih that i have corrected. and changed to i. in such case its printing only 0 value .